# Why my function does not work when I use switch in it?

Tags: php, function, switch-statement, constants

I've function for removing words less than 2 characters. First version is working:

```
function delLess2($array, $less){
    $english = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    return preg_grep('~\A[^'.$english.']{'.$less.',}\z~u', $array);
}
```

Using function:

```
$words = array("ӯ","ӯро","ӯт","ғариб","афтода","даст", "ра");

delLess($words, 3);

// Output
Array
(
    [1] => ӯро
    [3] => ғариб
    [4] => афтода
    [5] => даст
)
```

But this updated version does not work:

```
function delLess(&$array, $less = 0, $lang = FALSE)
{
    $english = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    $russian = "ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ";

    define(ENGLISH, $english);
    define(RUSSIAN, $russian);

    switch ($lang) 
    {
        case ENGLISH:
            return preg_grep('~\A[^'.ENGLISH.']{'.$less.',}\z~u', $array);
            break;

        case RUSSIAN:
            return preg_grep('~\A[^'.RUSSIAN.']{'.$less.',}\z~u', $array);
            break;

        default:
            return false;       
    }   
}
```

Where in code I have an error? How can it be corrected?

Comment: Have you var_dumped `$lang` ? + the default value of `$lang` shouldn't be a boolean but your default language

Comment: What do you expect to pass as $lang?  Can you show an example of how you've called this updated code.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `switch`, PHP tries to match the variable (`$lang`) with one of the `case` clauses.  As you've defined these fields to be the alphabet you want to use rather than a code for the language, it won't match any of them.

An alternative and more scalable solution, would be to have an associative array of the language codes and the alphabet to use for that code...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$words = array("ӯ","ӯро","ӯт","ғариб","афтода","даст", "ра");

function delLess(&$array, $less = 0, $lang = 'en')
{
    $trans = ["en" => "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM",
            "ru" => "ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ"
    ];

    if ( isset($trans[$lang]))  {
        return preg_grep('~\A[^'.$trans[$lang].']{'.$less.',}\z~u', $array);
    }
    else    {
        return false;
    }
}

$test = delLess($words, 3, 'en');
print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a default language, and get rid of your constants.

```
<?php

$words = array("ӯ","ӯро","ӯт","ғариб","афтода","даст", "ра");

function delLess(&$array, $less = 0, $lang = 'ru')
{
    $english = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    $russian = "ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ";

    switch ($lang) 
    {
        case 'en':
            return preg_grep('~\A[^'.$english.']{'.$less.',}\z~u', $array);
            break;

        case 'ru':
            return preg_grep('~\A[^'.$russian.']{'.$less.',}\z~u', $array);
            break;

        default: 
            throw new Exception('unsupported language');      
    }   
}

var_dump(delLess($words, 3, 'en'));
```

Which give you :

```
array(4) { [1]=> string(6) "ӯро" [3]=> string(10) "ғариб" [4]=> string(12) "афтода" [5]=> string(8) "даст" }
```

Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/d5BYR